# How to insert values into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Newbie here. Need some advice. I would like to insert values into database and so far no error in the code. I cant figure out the problem why it fail to insert values into database

Here my code

```
            string Constr = @"Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=True;Database=DDLYBank";
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(Constr);
            string MainAccInfo = "Select AccountNo, HashValue from MainAcc Where HashValue = '" + ccinfo + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(MainAccInfo, Conn);
            SqlDataReader read1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();


            using (SqlCommand command = Conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "Insert INTO Record (AccountNo, HashValue, Debit, Balance, Date_Time, FingerPrint) Values (@AccountNo, @HashValue, @Debit, @Balance, @Date_Time, @FingerPrint)";

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNo", read1["AccountNo"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HashValue", read1["HashValue"]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Debit", rDebit);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", aBalance);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Time", rDate);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FingerPrint", rFingerPrint);

                Conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: You are missing the @ signs in front of your parameter names in the SQL command.

Comment: you mean this? "@AccountNo"
I have try it. Still cant else I would done it.

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: no. even "return;" replace with "throw;". Same result

Comment: Shouldn't the `Conn.Open()` be  before the executeReader call?

Comment: Whats with all the downvotes?

Comment: Bob Vale, Conn.Open() is fix... You right and it should be after SQLConnection and before String MainAccInfo.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are trying to do should not be done as is done :)
Do this with Stored Procedures in SQL Server.

```
CREATE PROC CreateNewFromHashValue
   @HashValue NVARCHAR(128),
   @Debit INT,
   @Balance INT,
   @Date DATETIME,
   @FingerPrint NVARCHAR(128)
AS

INSERT INTO Record (AccountNo, HashValue, Debit, Balance, Date_Time, FingerPrint)
SELECT AccountNo, HashValue,@Debit,@Balance,@Date,@FingerPrint
    FROM MainAcc 
     WHERE HashValue = @HashValue

SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM Record
    ORDER BY DESC

GO
```

then we call it from .NET:

```
        // create and open a connection object
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=True;Database=DDLYBank");
        try {
        conn.Open();

        // 1. create a command object identifying
        // the stored procedure
        SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("CreateNewFromHashValue", conn);

        // 2. set the command object so it knows
        // to execute a stored procedure
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // 3. add parameter to command, which
        // will be passed to the stored procedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HashValue","YOUR HashValue"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Debit",1)); // Your Debit,INT?
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Balance",1)); // Your Balance ,INT?
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date",DateTime.Now)); // datetime :)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FingerPrint","FingerPrint")); // FingerPrint

        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // NOT ONLY RETURN  HER !!! 
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }


    //Remember to to close conn then you are done.
    conn.Close();
```